# Net electrical load of a peptide

Tags: proteins, homework, amino-acids

I have to determine the electrical charge of the next peptide chain:

C - E - H - P

I know that this page is not there to raise doubts about this style, but I have looked for resources on the Internet and find nothing. Please explain to me how to determine the net load according to pH and the isoelectric point, so that I can take this as an example.

My teacher told me to get the necessary data from this table:

[image: Lehninger. Principles of Biochemistry - 6th Edition]

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, it gives me the solution. But, I still don't know how to do it on my own.